# Use of useNavigate through input with search type and go to page with by pressing the key Enter

Tags: reactjs

// The problem here is that by pressing any key, it goes to the home page

import React  from 'react'
import { Link , useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import './City.css'

const City = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate()

```
return (  
    <>
    
      <div className="row1">
        <div className="col-6">
            
                <Link  to='/' className="navbar-brand">Navbar</Link>
                
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
           
            <h3 className="wellcome">wellcome</h3>
            <h5 className="cities">please enter the city</h5>
            <input  onKeyDown={() => {navigate('/home')}} type="text" className="searchcity" placeholder='City'></input>
            
            </div>
        
      </div>
     
        </>
);
```

}

export default City;

Comment: Try to add "exact" before to='/about' in all route it will check whole path.